# Why facebook says my Image url is invalid?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

[Link to facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.chandrikadaily.com/contentspage.aspx?id=17745). Facebook share was working fine before I changed myhosting provider. Fb share now selects invalid image from this page

Comment: The error states ` value 'thumbimage.ashx?w=100&h=100&imgid=17745' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.` cause its not a URL. Make change and retest in debugger

Comment: should I start with http:// for a proper url

Comment: Yup, you should. Check out [here](http://ogp.me/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the Facebook's Object debugger error

> Object at URL 'http://www.yoursite.com/contentspage.aspx?id=17745' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value 'thumbimage.ashx?w=100&h=100&imgid=17745' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

To correct it, change

```
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbimage.ashx?w=100&amp;h=100&amp;imgid=17745">
```

to

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yoursite.com/thumbimage.ashx?w=100&amp;h=100&amp;imgid=17745" />
```

Suggestion as per facebook documentation, images has to atleat `200px` both dimesnsion and also add

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```

Comment: Done exactly this and am still getting the error.
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is the description" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http:/example.com/Speakers.aspx?speaker=44" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/test.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="315">

Debugger says: Object at URL '' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:image:url' of type 'url' was not provided.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Facebook's Object debugger you are encountering following error

> Object at URL 'http://www.yoursite.com/contentspage.aspx?id=17745' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value 'thumbimage.ashx?w=100&h=100&imgid=17745' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

To take corrective action you need to change your image meta tag from

```
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbimage.ashx?w=100&amp;h=100&amp;imgid=17745">
```

to something like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

As suggested [here](http://ogp.me/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to delete return line endigns

From:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="
  http://www.cave-canem.cat/fitxers/imatges/productes/81/328/medium_IMG_1764.JPG
">
```

To:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.cave-canem.cat/fitxers/imatges/productes/81/328/medium_IMG_1764.JPG">
```